# VBA find returns "nothing" in userform

Tags: excel, vba, find

I have a worksheet in which column "A" to "I" are filled with data. Column a contains dates from 30/11/2011 to 6/12/2011. I have a userform in which there are 2 optionbuttons. When the first is selected, all dates are used. When the second is selected 6 textboxes that can be used to enter a start- and an enddate. These dates are used to create a range with the all data/the selected interval. I used `.find` to make a range of the selected start- and enddate.

I wrote a code for this which works in a seperate module, but i can't get it to work within the userform because `range.Find` returns "nothing." It took me a while to get it to work in the module as well because `range.find` is difficult to use in combination with dates but now that it works I dont know why it doesn't work in the Userform.

I've searched the forum extensively but couldn't find anything that helps me. I hope it's just a typing error but I really can't find why it doesn't work.

This is the code in the module:

```
sub Find()
Dim Dates As Range   
Dim Data As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Dim RngStart As Range 
Dim RngEnd As Range
Dim RngDates As Range
Dim DateStart As String
Dim DateEnd As String

Dim TextboxDate1 As Long   'these variables represent the textboxvalues of the userform
Dim TextboxDate2 As Long
Dim TextboxMonth1 As Long
Dim TextboxMonth2 As Long
Dim TextboxYear1 As Long
Dim TextboxYear2 As Long
    TextboxDate1 = 2
    TextboxDate2 = 4
    TextboxMonth1 = 12
    TextboxMonth2 = 12
    TextboxYear1 = 2011
    TextboxYear2 = 2011
    
    
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blad1").Activate
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set Data = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
        Set Dates = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1))

DateStart = TextboxMonth1 & "/" & TextboxDate1 & "/" & TextboxYear1 '"12/2/2011"
DateEnd = TextboxMonth2 & "/" & TextboxDate2 & "/" & TextboxYear2 '"12/4/2011"
    Set RngStart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blad1").Columns("A").find(DateStart)
    Set RngEnd = Columns("a").find(what:=DateEnd, after:=Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    Set RngDates = Range(RngStart, RngEnd)
        MsgBox RngDates.Address 'should return A160:A447
End Sub
```

however, when I try to run this code in the userform, .find returns "nothing"

```
Dim Dates As Range
Dim Data As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim RngStart As Range
Dim RngEnd As Range
Dim RngDates As Range
Dim DateStart As String
Dim DateEnd As String

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blad1").Activate

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set Data = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
        Set Dates = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1))

If OptionButton1.Value = False And OptionButton2.Value = False Then
    MsgBox "specify time domain"
End If

If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    Set RngDates = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blad1").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1))
End If

If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    DateStart = TextboxMonth1 & "/" & TextboxDate1 & "/" & TextboxYear1 '"12/2/2011"
    DateEnd = TextboxMonth2 & "/" & TextboxDate2 & "/" & TextboxYear2 '"12/4/2011"
        Set RngStart = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("blad1").Columns("A").find(DateStart)
        Set RngEnd = Columns("a").find(what:=DateEnd, after:=Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
        Set RngDates = Range(RngStart, RngEnd)
            MsgBox RngDates.Address 'should return A160:A447
End If
```

I can see that DateStart and DateEnd are properly defined, the code just doesn't manage to return the cells where the dates are found and gives me a runtime error 1004: method 'range of object '_global' failed, because i tried to set rngdates as a range from nothing to nothing.

Edit: It might be help to know that when i run the entire code with the first optionbutton selected i can afterwards use the seperate module to create the range `RngDates` however, when i run the code using the second selection and i stop it after it crashes, the seperate module won't find the desired cells either.

edit: to clarify it's about the dates december 2nd 2011 to december 4th 2011, not february.

Comment: I am surprised you can get this to work at all.  Excel stores dates as days since 1Jan1900. "12/2/2011" is just a display value.  Try `debug.Print clng(dateserial(2011,11,30))`, for example, and see what is displayed.

Comment: @TonyDallimore I've had some trouble finding dates indeed, but this link: [http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeVBA.htm](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DateTimeVBA.htm) contains a small explanation on using find with dates at the bottom of the page. I've also tried different things with formatting but with little to no succes.

Comment: I have not tried the ideas in the link you give but I think their is a misprint.  `"12/2/2011"` is not a standard date format in Excel. I think they mean #2/12/2011#.  An American Civilian style date between hashes is a date literal for VBA.

Comment: I've tried a date between hashes in the running module, but this resulted in finding 'nothing,' while "12/2/2011" results in finding the correct cells. It's the code in the userform that i somehow can't get to work, also not with the dateformat between hashes you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filled column A of worksheet “Sheet1” with some dates.

I created a form with the following controls:

- Text box: txtDate
- Command button: cmdFind
- Label: lblResult

This is the code within the form:

```
Private Sub cmdFind_Click()

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim DateDat As Date

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    DateDat = CDate(txtDate)

    Set Rng = .Columns("A").Find(What:=DateDat)

    If Rng Is Nothing Then
      lblResult.Caption = Format(DateDat, "d mmm yyyy") & " not found"
    Else
      lblResult.Caption = Format(DateDat, "d mmm yyyy") & " found in " & _
                          Replace(Rng.Address, "$", "")
    End If

  End With

End Sub
```

Each time I enter a date into the text box and click the button, the result of the Find is displayed in the label.  `CDate` is a bit fussy about what constitutes a date but apart from this I have no difficulty in finding dates with this code.

**Note** the variable in the Find statement is of type `Date`.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. I added an extra variable with `Cdate` and searched for that which returned the right cells

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.Find` to set `RngStart`, you specify the workbook and worksheet, but when you use `.Find` to get `RngEnd` you don't specify the worksheet.

This may lead to a failure to Find.

Comment: That's true, and it's not clean but it's not what causes the problem. Both `RngStart` and `RngEnd` are ''nothing'' in the userform, and in the module `.find` is able to find both of them.